# Handling events of objects that were created in lists

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, event-handling

I'm making a Scrabble game in Visual Basic.  In my project, I created a list of labels that will make up my "tiles" of the game board.  I'm just wondering how I would handle events for labels in the list, because they aren't objects that I created in the designer. (ex: Click, Hover events)

Here is the code that creates the grid of labels:

```
Dim labels As New List(Of Label)

For i = 0 To 10
        For y = 0 To 10
            Dim temp As New Label
            With temp
                Dim nfont As New Font("Fixedsys Excelsior 2.00", 15)
                .Name = Str(i)
                .AllowDrop = True
                .BackColor = Color.White
                .Location = New Point(y * 55 + 465, i * 45)
                .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 50)
                .Visible = True
                .Image = Image.FromFile("E:\Scrabble\Images\Blank.png")
                .CreateControl()
                .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                .ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen
                .Font = nfont
            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(temp)
            labels.Add(temp)
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add the handler before adding the label in the list:

```
AddHandler temp.Click, AddressOf LabelClickHandler
Me.Controls.Add(temp)
labels.Add(temp)
```